# Which WordPress forum plugin is best to use for a corporate site?

Tags: wordpress, forum

A client wants a forum incorporated into their site and suggested I use Zikula PHP framework. I decided to do a research and found:

- [ppPress](http://bbpress.org) and
- [Simple Press Forum](http://simplepressforum.com).

I wouldn't want to start experimenting here, you know. I want to know the best forum plugin available for WordPress.

Answer (score 1):

Our forum plugin, [WordPress Forum Plugin](http://www.wordpressforumplugin.com) may provide the features you are looking for.

It is built on top of MyBB, a powerful and capable forum package.  Our plugin integrates it seamlessly into WordPress and is easy to administer while still providing your users a rich forum experience.  We are also still in beta but are actively looking for a few more testers before we release (which should be pretty soon!)

Answer (score -1):

You could try Ninja Post --- [http://www.ninjapost.com][1] --- Although still in beta, Ninja Post can be integrated with WordPress.

In addition, Ninja Post integrates with Twitter and Facebook, and threads update in real time, like mini-chat rooms.